# Check if any email account setup in android

Tags: android, email

How can I check in android if any email account is set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) for checking the google accounts on an android phone :

```
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();

    for (Account account : accounts) {
    //do something with account
    }
```

Comment: Beware this method requires  GET_ACCOUNTS  runtime permission=> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccounts()