# Can an app recoginze that the user created a google account?

Tags: android, events, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if any email account setup in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505235/check-if-any-email-account-setup-in-android)

Hi is there any way to know that the user created new google account inside my app?
By intent or by event or any other way ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> List the available accounts using `getAccountsByType(String)` or
>   `getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures(String, String[], AccountManagerCallback,`
>   `Handler)`. Normally applications will only be interested in accounts
>   with one particular type, which identifies the authenticator. Account
>   features are used to identify particular account subtypes and
>   capabilities. Both the account type and features are
>   authenticator-specific strings, and must be known by the application
>   in coordination with its preferred authenticators.

```
public boolean isThereGoogleAccount(){
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this); 
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google"); 
    if (accounts.length > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This would create a google account if one is not already present.

```
AccountManager accountMgr = AccountManager.get(mContext);
accountMgr.addAccount("com.google", "ah", null, new Bundle(), (Activity) mContext, null, null);
```

"ah" is the authorization token type.

Comment: Author wants to know if account is already exist, not create a new.